# Creating a floating menu that pops like normal menu but appears at mouse position

Tags: linux, user-interface, gnome

#### Some context

I've recently switched to ubuntu budgie (from unity), and I am really tired of the Plank/panel menu combo. I cannot find a setting that suits me, because depending on my screen setup, there's always something in the wrong place.

I am literally unable to show the menu on certain edges if I activate auto-hide, and if I don't activate it, it's not nice at all, to the point that I have removed the plank thing altogether. (Am I having strange bugs on this OS, or is it really messy?)

#### My idea

With great frustrations come new ideas. I thought again about one I had in the past. I would like to have a circle menu that pops around my mouse cursor when I press a given key combination (very much the kind of thing you would find in some games).

The main use case is to get "pined" application shortcuts easily when I need them, but perhaps other things would fit well with them (commands ...).

#### Questions

So my questions are:

1. Does such a thing already exist?
2. If it doesn't, is it difficult to realize? (How much time, complexity, ...)
3. What tools/libraries are needed for such a project? I know I'll find plenty of explanations on the [gnome developer website](https://developer.gnome.org) but I could really use some more help.

Comment: Comment rather than a definitive answer - If you were running xfce then xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu with an empty panel would display an appmenu at your cursor.  Suggest have a look at that code to judge the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention a buggy behaviour on Plank, depending on the screen configuration, I suspect you are suffering from [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/plank/+bug/1755731). In short: Plank's returned values for the space it needs are not always correct in multi monitor setup.

A neat option to replace at least part of the functionality is [Ulauncher](https://ulauncher.io/), by default called from a shortcut, but you could trigger it from anything that is capable of running its command.

[image]

Since Ulauncher's window simply identifies in the window list, you can easily write a script to move it to the current mouse position.
In case you'd need any help in that, just leave a comment.

Not sure if you are also referring to quick access of the window list, but for that you could use the Window Previews applet, or even the Workspace Overview applet, so life without Plank is possible.

[image]

Comment: The bug you mention seems to play a role but there is more to it, and it maybe by design (or lack of). For instance, you can't have plank and the budgie-panel on the same edge (I would put one under/over/aside the other).
-- Also, you can't open a hidden panel/plank with certain hiding options (I know about the double mousehover, it does not work all the time); Notably when the said panel/plank is on a middle edge (between 2 screens), it is impossible to open it.

Comment: Ulauncher is great, I'm looking for a way to add always visible shortcuts (not only the often used ones). Thanks for this :-)